# Approximating a product-measurable function from below

Tags: measure-theory

On page 198 of Dunford and Schwartz, Vol. I, in the proof of part (b) of Lemma III.11.16, the following assertion is made without proof (or reference).  Let $(X,\mathscr{X},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathscr{Y},\nu)$ be finite measure spaces, and $(X\times Y, \mathscr{X}\otimes\mathscr{Y},\mu\times\nu)$ be their product space.  If $f\colon X\times Y\to [0,\infty)$ is measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{X}\otimes\mathscr{Y}$, then $f$ can be approximated a.e. by a sequence $f_n$ of finite linear combinations of characteristic functions of sets of the form $A\times B$, $A\in\mathscr{X}$, $B\in\mathscr{Y}$ (this is standard so far), *and one may in addition assume that* $f_n\leqslant f $ a.e. *for all* $n$.  Is this (last statement) entirely obvious?

Comment: I deleted my wrong answer, so I rewrite the observations I made. 1. It's enough to consider $f=\chi_A$, where $A\in\cal X\otimes\cal Y$. 2. Here, the product measure is unique determined. It is constructed by considering the outer measure. In particular, each set can be approximated _from above_ by a countable union of set of the form $A\times B$, $A\in\cal X$ and $B\in\cal Y$. But it _a priori_ doesn't tell anything about an inner approximation.

Comment: I think your observations are correct.  Here is another question.  Given a set $E\in \mathscr{X}\otimes\mathscr{Y}$ of positive $\mu\times\nu$ measure, can one always find a cartesian product $A\times B$, $A\in\mathscr{X}$, $B\in\mathscr{Y}$, such that $(\mu\times\nu)(A\times B)>0$ and $A\times B\subseteq E$?  For then one might exhaust $E$ by a countable union of pairwise disjoint sets $A\times B$ of positive $\mu\times\nu$ measure by transfinite induction?  @DavideGiraudo

Comment: It's also an interesting question. It would be good to handle it in the case where $(X,\cal X)$ and $(Y,\cal Y)$ are compact metric spaces endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the statement is wrong.  As I was browsing through the questions on the right of this screen, I came across the books by Fremlin and Bogachev (in the question with title "Uniqueness of product measure (non $\sigma$-finite case)").  Exercise 3.10.62 of Bogachev's book is as follows (p. 235).  Given atomless probability spaces $(X_1,\mathcal{A_1},\mu_1)$ and $(X_2,\mathcal{A_2},\mu_2)$, there exists a set $A\in\mathcal{A_1}\otimes\mathcal{A_2}$, with $(\mu_1\otimes\mu_2)(A)>0$, such that $(\mu_1\otimes\mu_2)((A_1\times A_2)\setminus A)>0$ for any sets $A_1\in\mathcal{A}_1$, $A_2\in\mathcal{A_2}$ with $\mu_1(A_1)\mu_2(A_2)>0$.

In fact this is proved in a paper by Erdos and Oxtoby (Trans. AMS **79** (1955), 91--102).  Let $(X_1,\mathcal{A_1},\mu_1)$ and $(X_2,\mathcal{A_2},\mu_2)$ be both the unit interval $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.  Let $D'$ be a fat Cantor set in the unit interval, i.e., a nowhere dense compact set of Lebesgue measure $\lambda_1(D')\in (0,1)$, where $\lambda_1$ is linear Lebesgue measure.  Let $D:=D'\cup(-D')$.  Now set $A:=\{ (x,y)\in [0,1]^2\colon x-y\in D\}$.  This is Borel measurable, being the inverse image of $D$ under the continuous map $(x,y)\mapsto x-y$.  With $\lambda_2$ denoting two-dimensional Lebesgue measure, for $A_1,A_2$ Borel subsets of $[0,1]$ one then has that \begin{align*}\lambda_2(A^c\cap (A_1\times A_2))&=\int\int\mathbf{1}_{D^c}(x-y)\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(x)\mathbf{1}_{A_2}(y)\, dx\, dy\\ &= \int_0^1\int_{-1}^1\mathbf{1}_{D^c}(u)\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(u+v)\mathbf{1}_{A_2}(v)\, du\, dv = \int_{[-1,1]\cap D^c} f(u)\, du,\end{align*} where $f(u):=\int\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(u+v)\mathbf{1}_{A_2}(v)\, dv =\lambda_1(A_1\cap(A_2+u))$.  The function $f$ is non-negative and continuous, $f(-u)=\mathbf{1}_{-A_1}\ast\mathbf{1}_{A_2}(u)$ being the convolution of two $L^2$-functions; moreover, the same calculation shows that $\int f(u)\, du=\lambda_2(A_1\times A_2)$, which is positive if $\lambda_1(A_1)\lambda_1(A_2)>0$.  It follows that $f$ is positive on some interval $I=(a,b)$, say, contained in $[-1,1]$ (since $f=0$ outside $[-1,1]$).  Since $I\cap D^c$ is open and non-empty (as $I$ cannot be contained in $D$ it being nowhere dense in $[-1,1]$), it has positive linear Lebesgue measure.  Thus \begin{equation*}\lambda_2(A^c\cap (A_1\times A_2))=\int_{[-1,1]\cap D^c} f(u)\, du\geqslant \int_{I\cap D^c} f(u)\, du>0\end{equation*} when $\lambda_1(A_1)\lambda_1(A_2)>0$.  Note also that, by the same calculation as above, one has that \begin{equation*} \lambda_2(A)=\lambda_2(A\cap [0,1]^2)= \int_D \lambda_1([0,1]\cap ([0,1]+u))\, du=\int_D (1-|u|)\, du\end{equation*} which is positive, since $D$ is of positive linear Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Nice! So I don't worry about the fact I wasn't able to show it.

Comment: Yes, me neither.  Thanks for your interest.  Of course the question remains (to me) whether the Lemma in Dunford and Schwartz is valid.  I think I'll ask in Mathoverflow, where some expert in Bochner integrability might see it and know the answer.  @DavideGiraudo